# How to change CSS property using variable in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So I'm trying to change the animation of speed of something on my page, however when I try and use a variable name in the string portion the animation breaks. I'm sure this just has to do with how I am handling the string, but I already tried a couple of alternatives and my animation still breaks either way. If somehow could advise me I would be appreciative.

```
var speed = 5;
speed = speed.toString() + 's infinite';

$('#ball').click(function () {
    $('#ball').css('animation', 'bounce' + speed);
});
```

Comment: what is your css, can you make little sample ?

Comment: for a start, you should have a space in your string: `"bounce " + speed);`

Comment: Ah ok, I see that now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Bottom features include an animation;

```
animation-name: initial;
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-timing-function: bounce;
animation-delay: initial;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: initial;
animation-fill-mode: initial;
animation-play-state: initial;
```

Animation enriched by editing with them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's much better just update the classname for instance you have a two classes:

```
.animate {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera         */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.slower{
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

And then you handle this with jQuery as follows:

```
$('#ball').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('slower');
});
```